# Library for support asynchronous servlet on Java EE 5

Tags: servlet-3.0, java-ee-5

I have question If exist some library for Java EE 5 which allows to support asynchronous servlet on Java EE 5?

Answer (score 0):

We used the [Quartz scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) in a Tomcat based JavaEE 5 application to process asynchronous tasks.